# How to access the UIScrollView type from a SwiftUI ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I need a way to get reference to the `UIScrollView` that is under the hood of the SwiftUI `ScrollView`.

Does anyone have any neat extensions to do this?

Looking for something like -

```
ScrollView {
  [ItemsList]
}
.getScrollView { scrollView in // This is a UIScrollView type
   
}
```

Comment: The is no one. I'm not sure (can't remember) if there was in SwitfUI 1.0, but now it is pure SwiftUI type.

Comment: Why would you want to do that. Please elaborate a little bit more, perhaps there is another solution.

Comment: Introspect may or may not offer a similar solution. I don't know where they stand with ScrollView but it changes with every update. It isn't reliable.

Comment: I want to do this is because I am using a UIKit framework for bottom sheets called [Duvet](https://github.com/livefront/duvet). I have my swiftUI scrollView imbedded in the bottom sheet. There is an option to pass in a `UIScrollView` to the Duvet sheet that will track scrolling. This is why I want to grab reference to the sheet so I can track scrolling on my resizable bottom sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`Introspect for SwiftUI` does exactly that. However, it is not very reliable.

There is actually an implementation for the `SwiftUI ScrollView`. You can get hold of the underlying `UIKit UIScrollView` by using `.introspectScrollView()`.

```swift
ScrollView {
    Text("Hello World")
}
.introspectScrollView { scrollView in
    scrollView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
}
```

You can find it on GitHub: [Introspect for SwiftUI](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

Tell us more about your use case, there is certainly a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you @christophriepe, the reason I want to do this is because I am using a UIKit framework for bottom sheets called [Duvet](https://github.com/livefront/duvet). I have my swiftUI scrollView imbedded in the bottom sheet. There is an option to pass in a `UIScrollView` to the Duvet sheet that will track scrolling. This is why I want to grab reference to the sheet so I can track scrolling on my resizable bottom sheet.

Comment: @AlexanderRuben Ok, in this case `Introspect for SwiftUI` should do the job. Just keep in mind, that it may not be 100% reliable.